# How do I calculate the molarity of a 40% w/v HCl solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry

> A 40% hydrochloric acid (w/v) is found to have density of 1.20g /mL. The molarity of the solution is nearly?

Comment: I think that you're missing something

Comment: @creek Well, if you can assume the molar mass of $HCl$ is 36.5g (or any value for that matter... just as long as you're permitted to calculate the molar mass on your own, since it isn't given in the question), then you're all set to solve it (it's *anything* but "straightforward" though... took me a quite while to figure it out) O:)

Comment: As someone said: "less is more"

Answer (score 1):

First we need the molecular weight of $\ce{HCl}$:
$$\pu{1.008 g//mol} + \pu{35.453 g//mol} = \pu{36.461 g//mol}$$

Now the tricky part is that $40\%~\mathrm{w/v}$ means $\pu{40 g}$ in $\pu{100 mL}$ solution, not in $\pu{100 g}$ solution, so you don't need the density. If the question asked for molality instead of molarity, density would have been required.
So now we write down what $40\%~\mathrm{w/v}~\ce{HCl}$ means and use unit factors to walk our given units to the desired units, canceling the bad units and replacing them with the good as we march inexorably along:
$$\require{cancel}\left[\frac{40\text{ }\color{red}{\bcancel{\color{black}{\text{g HCl}}}}}{100\text{ }\color{blue}{\bcancel{\color{black}{\text{mL}}}}\text{sol'n}}\right]\left[\frac{1000\text{ }\color{blue}{\bcancel{\color{black}{\text{mL}}}}}{1\text{ L}}\right]\left[\frac{1\text{ mol HCl}}{36.461\text{ }\color{red}{\bcancel{\color{black}{\text{g HCl}}}}}\right]=\frac{10.97\text{ mol HCl}}{1\text{ L sol'n}}=11.0\text{ M}$$

Comment: I'd agree that you have worked out 40 % w/v HCl correctly. After seeing your work I deleted my answer which was wrong.

Comment: @MaxW Correctness is not as important as the test of illustrating the unit factors method via MathJax. I think it makes it much more readable to be able to cancel out in matching colors, and I believe that the unit factors method should be taught to posters who are green enough to want help on their general chemistry homework. Do you think the layout of my answer in MathJax looks readable?

Comment: It is a fantastic answer. The MathJax is beautiful.

Comment: I down-voted this answer, because it is far from being exceptional enough to keep questions like these on the site. Also, the first sentences of any answer should be: "The concentration % (w/v) does not make any sense. Don't use it!"